# Construct a new feasible solution from an old one

Tags: analysis, probability-distributions, linear-programming, constraints, constructive-mathematics

**The Problem**

Here is a part of the constraint of a linear programming.
$$
        \begin{align}
                          \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\pi_n=1,\;\pi_n&> 0,\forall n\geq0.,\\
                          \displaystyle 0<a\leq \frac{\pi_{n+1}}{\pi_n}\leq b&<1,\forall n\geq0.
        \end{align}
$$

As we can see, $\pi_n$ is a probability distribution. $\pi_n$ is strictly decreasing, and the decrease speed has an upper bound $b$ and a lower bound $a$.

What I want to do is **construct a new feasible solution from an old one**. The **new solution is decreasing at the slowest speed, that is $b$,  before a constant $N^*\in N$.**  Formally, given any feasible solution $\{\pi_n,n\geq 0\}$, the aim is to construct a new feasible solution like

$$\widetilde\pi_n=\left\{
        \begin{align}
                          &\square\pi_0b^n, &0\leq n\leq N^*,\\
                          &\square, &n> N^*.
        \end{align}
        \right.$$

**My Idea**

My idea is straight. Just use a normalization constant $Z$ as follows,

$$\widetilde\pi_n=\left\{
        \begin{align}
                          &\frac{1}{Z}\pi_0b^n, &0\leq n\leq N^*,\\
                          &\frac{1}{Z}\pi_n, &n> N^*.
        \end{align}
        \right.$$
where $Z=\sum_{n=0}^{N^*}\pi_0b^n+\sum_{n=N^*+1}^{\infty}\pi_n$. But $\widetilde\pi_n$ doesn't add up at $N^*$.

Can anyone give me a feasible solution or some hints? Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't $\ \tilde{\pi}_n\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}(1-b)b^n\ $ satisfy your requirements?  Is there some other restriction on the new solution that you haven't specified?